# Affects of changing email address of an Amazon account on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

My client wants me to change email address we are using for an Amazon account and AWS.
We are using an s3 server and an EC2 instance with a static ip.

I tried to look at the documents but couldn't find an exact answer. Logically it shouldn't affect anything but I want to be sure.

If we change email address will any of the following will be changed?

-AWS Access Key ID
-Secret Access Key 
-x509 certificates 
-.pem file to connect to EC2 server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of your API credentials will be impacted. You can change the email address associated with your AWS account with no impact on your running services.